# Convert A to ASCII Int and add +1 so it gets "B"

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I need to convert an `int` to the `char` and the `char` back to an `int`.

I have an `"A"` and I want it to get a `"B"`, so I need to convert `"A"` to an `int`, then add `1` to it, then convert it back to an `char`.

Pseudo Code:

```
char s = "A";
int i = s.toInt;
i + 1;
s = i.toChar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the `++` operator on it:

```
char s = 'A';
s++;
// s = 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this by implicit castings:

```
char s = 'A';
int i = (int)s;
i++;
s = (char)i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is an implicit conversation between `char` and `int`, you can easily use [`++` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) for a character.

```
var A = 'A';
Console.WriteLine(++A); // B
```

Remember, [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char) is *already* 2 byte numeric value.